# No Activity found to handle Intent (MMS on Sony Xperia)

Tags: android, android-intent

We have an app, where we're attaching an image to an MMS on Android, and we've tested it on Galaxy S4 and S6, but a client is testing it on Xperia Z3 Compact and is experiencing problems with the intent for attaching the image...

Specifically, we're getting the following error from him:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0x10000001 pkg=com.android.mms (has clip) (has extras) }
```

So this is the way we're adding the image:

```
Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);                                        picMessageIntent.setPackage("com.android.mms");
picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
picMessageIntent.setType("image/png");
picMessageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(picMessageIntent);
```

In our manifest we have:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

We've tried with:

```
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.intent_chooser));
chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(chooser);
```

But that just gives the error that no valid activity can be found for the action... The weird part is, the client is testing it in the message app, and we want to use the message app... So, is there an issue on some Android phones with getting access to it?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was:

```
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this);
Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
picMessageIntent.setType("image/png");
picMessageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
    picMessageIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
}
```